# Was Fate: The Winx Saga influenced by The Bastard Son and the Devil Himself (or vice versa)?

Tags: the-bastard-son-the-devil-himself, fate-the-winx-saga

*Fate: The Winx Saga* and *The Bastard Son and the Devil Himself* are shows from Netflix. The second season of the first show was released a few months before the first season of the second show, and there are a few notable similarities in their plot points and worlds:

- Both seasons feature people denominated as "blood witches."
- In both shows, the blood witches are hated, feared, and marginalized by Fairborn witches/fairies after a previous conflict.
- Both seasons prominently feature blood witch villains who steal powers from fairies/Fairborn witches to become more powerful and who seek revenge for the wrongs committed against their group.

These similarities seem not insignificant, especially considering that the shows come from the same company in the same year at almost the same time. Is there any evidence that one show influenced the other, or that the source material for one influenced the source material for the other?

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at the dates the source material was created Half Bad (the influence for The Bastard Son and the Devil Himself) was first published as a book in 2014

fate the Winx Saga is based on a Nikleodian animated TV series that ran from 2004 to 2009 so if one influenced the other then I would suggest that Half Bad was influenced by the Winx Saga.

However I think the claim that is the case is tenuous at best. While the themes are similar there is no indication that Sally Green had any influence from the Winx Saga in writing Half Bad. What is more likely is that this is an extreme case of Twinning, which is a well known phenomenon in move production where movies with similar themes are developed at the same time. The reason this is more extreme is that the same company is involved in the production of both, although Half Bad is also produced by Andy Serkis production company. I can't find anywhere if Netflix or Andy Serkis got involved first.

The reasons for similar productions like this is usually a combination of research companies realising a gap or want or need in the market leading to production companies looking for products that fill that gap, combined with writers finding themselves independently exploring similar themes, either because of some exterior influence (state of the world, a feel that people need a certain story). Or the fact that they have not seen a story like that being written in a while if ever. Examples of this are Armageddon and Deep Impact, and White House Down and Olympus has Fallen.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twin_films

But I would say these 2 shows are very very different and it is more likely that the similarities you see in them are due to both stories drawing from the same original influences concerning the power of Witches/faries, conflict between covens and groups and the links between taking the powers from a stronger witch/fairy. The fact is that at it's heart the key difference is that one of these is about Witches and the other is about Faries and the main story is different between them.

Comment: Citation or link for "twinning"?

Answer (score -2):

They are both the same show and script the first, based on an American take of the tale the second based on the English version of it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I know they seem that way, but I am fairly certain that is not the case.

Comment: As per my answer they are based on 2 very different sources, The Bastard Son and the Devil Himself is based on a Book series, and the Winx Saga is based off of a Nikelodian cartoon.